# htaccess wildcard redirect not redirecting with the trailing slash on the domain name

Tags: .htaccess

Here's the code I have in my .htaccess file right now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^centerforpolicyanalysis.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.centerforpolicyanalysis.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.equalhealth\.info$1" [R=301,L]
```

I want to redirect everyone who visits http://(www.)centerforpolicyanalysis.org to http://www.equalhealth.info

it works fine if that's all you type in the url, but if you type a subdirectory, it fails.

here's what I'm getting:
I type

```
http://www.centerforpolicyanalysis.org/index.php/2011/06/recommendations-for-preventive-services-to-women-and-girls/
```

and I get

```
http://www.equalhealth.infoindex.php/2011/06/recommendations-for-preventive-services-to-women-and-girls/
```

And it breaks. How do I get it to keep the trailing slash on the domain name on redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?centerforpolicyanalysis\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.equalhealth.info%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```